# Why I can't interact with my follower (Diablo 3)

Tags: diablo-iii

When I try to right-click follower icon, talk button/link is disabled, why?

How can I check their inventory etc...?

Comment: You can't interact with the initial templar that you get in the dungeon (Cormac is the name I think). Is this the one you are talking about?

Comment: The talk button is disabled when there is nothing to talk about. But depending on the quest you are doing it is possible that you can talk with your follower/companion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to interact with when they're hired. By default, you can hit F to bring up the Inventory of the follower. This will allow you to swap gear. You should also be able to right click on their follower icon to reset the spells.

Comment: I tryed, nothing happens if I press "F", i checked options if i unbinded it perhaps, but i haven't so it should work :S Not sure why it doesn't :S

Comment: I hired another follower and then again the templar and it started to work :S

Comment: @Adrov: I've had some issues with followers in the past too. In that case I restarted the quest and it was fine then (it wasn't a hireling that was having issues).